# migrar de visual studio 2012 a visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes de ante mano muchas gracias por cualquier colaboracion,les cuento tenia un proyecto en vs2012 y cambie a vs2015 pero el único error que me sale luego de la migración es un problema con el `ReportViewer`

```html
 Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

this.reportViewer1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
```

cada vez que aparece `Reporting` me lo señala como error 
también me sale
[image: esto en vs2012 no salia]

y decidi generar el .exe

y al ejecutarlo me sale

[image: y ya lo descargue y aun nada]

y ya lo descargue y aun nada

que puedo hacer para no volver a vs2012?

Comment: revisaste que efectivamente esta en la ruta? C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta ejecutando desde línea de comandos del `Nuget`lo siguiente:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes.... elimina la referencia del ensamblado y busca agregarla de nuevo.... seguramente vas a encontrar una version mas nueva que ma que tenias ya que la version de vs ha cambiado y el ensamblado tambien